# jQuery show hide not working in Chrome and FF

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to do a simple show/hide on three divs. It's working fine in IE but the onClick functions aren't working in Chrome or FireFox.

Here's my code (with the div content simplified):

```js
$(function showHide() {
  $("#showaudience").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").show();
  });
  $("#showbehavior").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").show();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
  $("#showacquisition").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").show();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="showaudience" value="Audience" onClick="showHide"></input>
  <input type="button" id="showbehavior" value="Behavior" onClick="showHide"></input>
  <input type="button" id="showacquisition" value="Acquisition" onClick="showHide"></input>
</div>

<div id="audience" style="display:block;">Audience Data</div>
<div id="behavior" style="display:none;">Behavior Data</div>
<div id="acquisition" style="display:none;">Acquisition Data</div>
```

Comment: Erm, yes they are. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 43.0.2357.65 m - It works when I run it in JS Fiddle on Chrome, but when I preview it on my dev server in Chrome it does not.

Comment: A simple suggestion that's not related to your issue: you should add a class to all your buttons and simply trigger `$('.myClass').hide(); $('#myButton').show()` or even concatenate your calls `$('#myClass1, #myClass2').hide()` it would save a few lines and jQuery calls. For 3 buttons it might look unecessary, but if you ever have 20 it might be useful.

Comment: the Snippet works fine. make sure your page haves the link correctly linked to jquery. we cannot say much more...

Comment: Why would you put your event listener bindings within the `showHide()` function? That means you need to call the `showHide()` function for the click event listeners to be added... isn't it flawed logic? (genuinely curious)

Comment: For anyone reading this question having a similar issue: the problem was that jQuery was not correctly defined.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `onClick="showHide"` its not required.

Since you are already bind event handler with jQuery you don't need to use inline click handler. Also its syntax is not correct.

Also, Modify `input` as it is empty element

```
<input type="button" id="showaudience" value="Audience" />
```

```js
$(function showHide() {
  $("#showaudience").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").show();
  });
  $("#showbehavior").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").show();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
  $("#showacquisition").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").show();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="showaudience" value="Audience" />
  <input type="button" id="showbehavior" value="Behavior" />
  <input type="button" id="showacquisition" value="Acquisition" />
</div>

<div id="audience" style="display:block;">Audience Data</div>
<div id="behavior" style="display:none;">Behavior Data</div>
<div id="acquisition" style="display:none;">Acquisition Data</div>
```

Comment: And make sure it's wrapped in the document ready function http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @GeorgeLee, Op has already wrapped in document-ready handler. He has provide `showHide` name

Comment: Actually if OP removed the `onClick="showHide"` and left everything else the same, the `showHide` function would never run, so the `click` handlers would never be applied to the buttons. Instead of having the `showHide` function, OP should just make the bindings directly in the onLoad jQuery function.

Comment: @Satpal This may be a stupid question, how can you tell as I can't see it in the js?

Comment: `$(function(){ //here is your onload logic });` would be the onload function shorthand... I don't know what OP is trying to do exactly...

Comment: @Satpal You know I never knew you could do that, I thought you had you use `$(document).ready()`, thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeLee, Please go through the link which you provided

Comment: @Christine, Test my code snippet,  __even your code snippet works__

Comment: @Satpal Your code snippet didn't work for me on my dev server. My snippet works within this environment which is why this is so frustrating. On my dev server, my code works in IE, but not Chrome or FireFox...go figure

Comment: @Christine, Try once with removing `showHide` from `$(function showHide() {` and check are you getting any error in your browser console

Comment: @Satpal I'm getting this error: $ is not defined on this line: $(function showHide() { . I get it with or without showHide included

Comment: @Christine, Then jQuery is not load check that the path to file is correct. Try once with `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I was missing the "s" in my http://...... I hate these little things that throw a wrench in everything! Thanks for helping me find the issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your jQuery `onLoad` handler to apply the click handlers directly to the button elements, and remove the `onclick` attributes from them, and also make the `<input />` tags self-contained, because they don't need closing tags.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#showaudience").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").show();
  });
  $("#showbehavior").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").show();
    $("#acquisition").hide();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
  $("#showacquisition").click(function() {
    $("#behavior").hide();
    $("#acquisition").show();
    $("#audience").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="showaudience" value="Audience"/>
  <input type="button" id="showbehavior" value="Behavior"/>
  <input type="button" id="showacquisition" value="Acquisition"/>
</div>

<div id="audience" style="display:block;">Audience Data</div>
<div id="behavior" style="display:none;">Behavior Data</div>
<div id="acquisition" style="display:none;">Acquisition Data</div>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, I didn't orginally have the onclick attributes on my buttons and tried adding them because I couldn't get it to work.